# cURL Get image from link

Tags: php, curl

I have a script in php how download images from a partner website.

The script looks like

```html
function getimg($url) {
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
    $user_agent = 'php';
    $process = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
 curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($process);
    curl_close($process);
    return $return;
}
```

The problem is because partner was put a password on his website. the website url is www.importatorarticolecopii.ro/feeds/general_feed2.php

I put the user and password in curl but not work...

Need some help

Comment: That wasn't the real password you just posted on here was it? Probably not a good idea! Oh yeah, it totally was. You need to change that now!

Comment: Is not a problem the site is not secret :-) is just a security method from my partnet

Comment: Are you using that URL, or a URL pointing to an image? It may not be working because you're only accepting image types, but that URL isn't an image.

Comment: Yes theat url poit to url image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, the problem is from your given url
Increase your timeout as the url given above is too slow and try to don't exceed the maximum execution time of your server.

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
```

and use a user agent for example :

```
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/2php0050915 Firefox/1.0.7)';
```

and in future try to catch your errors to check what's your issue

```
if(curl_error($process))
{
echo 'error:' . curl_error($process);
}
```